# UIImageView not loading in UITableViewCell until scrolled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am having a problem with a UIImageView I am setting inside **tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** for some reason when the UITableView loads the bottom cell half in view dose not have the a Image loaded into the UIImageView like the rest of the UITableViewCells, however once I scroll then it works itself out.. But once doing so the top UItableViewCell then drops its image! untill i scroll that back into full view.

What I have done is created the UITableViewCell in Interface Builder and i have a blank UIImageView, I then set the UIImage I am going to place inside the UIImageView in ViewDidLoad then inside tableview:CellForRowAtIndexPath: I set it then return the cell.

heres the code

```
//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//..
storageCalcIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CALC.png"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    SeriesSearchResultItem *myObj = [[SeriesSearchResultItem alloc] init];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        //call obj array with all of the values from my sorting algorithum
        myObj = (SeriesSearchResultItem*)[dataArrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//.. assinging storageCalcIconImage inside if statment
firstSpaceImage.image = storageCalcIconImage;
//..
}
    return cell;
}
```

there is lots happening in tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath but I decided to drop the stuff that wasnt related to the image problem.. hopefully you guys can see an error I am making that I havent yet... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected result from the use of reusable cells inside a tableView. If you want to avoid this behavior you should create a cell for each rows of your tableView instead of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.
Expect huge performance impact if you have a lot of rows to display though.

Comment: How would one go about creating a cell for each row if your showing  dynamic amount of tableviewcells and information for those cells?

Comment: Your tableView usually display the content of an NSArray of objects. When you change the content of this NSArray, you just have to call `reloadData` on your tableView to display the refreshed data. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is just here to indicate to your tableView how to display a row at a specific indexPath.